# Why is radeontop showing 0,00% in all fields?

Tags: ati, radeon, performance, gpu

I'm trying to get realtime statistics about my graphics card utilization, and the program `radeontop` is supposed to enable that. However, as you can see in the screenshot below, it reports all the results as 0,00%:

[image]

I am sure that my GPU does in fact work (e.g. I can play TF2 with a nice framerate using the proprietary AMD driver, and a low but playable framerate using the free radeon one).

Here's the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` when using the **proprietary AMD driver**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.12798 Core Profile Context 13.35.1005
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
```

Here is the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` when using the **free radeon driver**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD BONAIRE
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

- **Model of card:** MSI Radeon HD 7790
- **Ubuntu version:** 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Need to use opensource driver

  > **radeontop** is a small utility which allows one to monitor the utilization of
  >   Radeon GPUs starting from the R600 series and newer using undocumented
  >   performance counters in the hardware. The utility works with the free
  >   drivers.

  So, it does not work with the proprietary driver.
- If you are using xubuntu or lubuntu or any non *composite*, you need to run 3d app like `glxgears`
- If it does not work. The original developer (under username: 
  curaga) made a post on Phoronix forums:

  [Announcing radeontop, a tool for viewing the GPU usage](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?72130-Announcing-radeontop-a-tool-for-viewing-the-GPU-usage)

  More interesting, one comment from him about BONAIRE card:

  > Patches welcome. Bonaire (7790/r260) is about five generations newer than my card, so I can't exactly test anything even close. ([original post](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?72130-Announcing-radeontop-a-tool-for-viewing-the-GPU-usage&p=413277#post413277))
  >
  > Anyone with a Bonaire, Kaveri, or Kabini, please test latest git. I have no such hw. ([original post](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?72130-Announcing-radeontop-a-tool-for-viewing-the-GPU-usage&p=413635#post413635))

  So, try installing it from source:

  https://github.com/clbr/radeontop

  Then file bug report there (github) for this if still no success.

Comment: Well, the results are the same with the free driver as well.

Comment: @jco, Could you repost the new `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` for the free radeon driver.

Comment: I did, just tell me if you need more info :)

Comment: @jco, I have updated answer.